# Wrong event being triggered on CheckBox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I have two CheckBoxes with the following code

```
Private Sub MasiveModeCkB_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MasiveModeCkB.CheckedChanged
    If MasiveModeCkB.Checked Then
        SendCommandsChkB.Checked = True
        SendCommandsChkB.Enabled = False
    Else
        SendCommandsChkB.Checked = False
        SendCommandsChkB.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SendCommandsChkB_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SendCommandsChkB.CheckedChanged
    DummyCount += 1

End Sub
```

The problem that I have is when I check SendCommand both CheckedChanged are triggered, I don't get why?
As you see in the above code I don't change the state of MasiveModeCkB inside the SendCommandsChkB_CheckedChanged. So why shot the event MasiveModeCkB_CheckedChanged?

Comment: How do you know MassiveMode gets a checkchanged when you click SendCommand?  If you are going by DummyCount, that will increment anytime either check box's state goes to Checked

Comment: is this on an asp.net web form? if yes, then what does your page_load look like? you might be resetting everything on the postback

Comment: Plutonix, I don't need SendCommandsChkB_CheckedChanged event, cause I read the Checked state from another part of the code, I just add that code because I see on the GUI that when I check SendCommandsChkB gets disabled and checked; and because the only part of the code where I do that is in MasiveModeCkB_CheckedChanged event, but I'm not click in on MasiveModeCkB, so why shoots the event of the wrong control?

Comment: mmeasor, is not a Web application, is a desktop application. The problem is that when I click on SendCommandsChkB shots MasiveMode event.

Comment: Do you have any AddHandler statements anywhere?

Comment: Hi Cris Dunaway, no, I have not AddHandler, but I have several Delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not happen when I copied your code. There are a couple of possibilities:

1. DummyCount may be initialized incorrectly, or it may result in a modification of MasiveModeCkB settings.
2. You may have the checkbox names and labels mixed up.
3. Something may be mixed up in the designer.

A. Try clearing out the checkboxes on the form, then add them again in the designer. If they were added programmatically, check the names and labels.

B. Set a breakpoint at `DummyCount += 1` and single-step from there to see what's happening.